# How to return NULL on LEFT JOIN when criteria produces no result for the 2nd table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have table `Account` that has zero-to-many `Subscription`, and I want to return `Account.name` and `Subscription.end`.

If there's no active subscription, `Subscription.end` should be `NULL`.

This is my (incorrect) SQL:

```
SELECT acc.name,
       s.t_end
FROM ACCOUNT acc LEFT JOIN SUBSCRIPTION s ON acc.id = s.account_id
WHERE acc.id = 1
  AND s.t_start <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
  AND s.t_end > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

**The problem with my SQL:** If there's no matching subscription for the account, it will return empty set:

```
acc.name | s.t_end
------------------
<nothing>
```

What I want:

```
acc.name | s.t_end
------------------
1        | NULL
```

Comment: This is exactly the purpose of LEFT JOIN. Not sure why your query didn't work. Can you give any sample data in sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: @PraveenE correct, but apparently if your WHERE makes 2nd table to not return anything, it won't return anything for everything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever using `Left Join`, if there are any `Where` conditions on the right-side tables; it will limit the data, and you will not get all the rows from the left-most table as desired.

Instead, you can shift the `Where` conditions on the right-side tables to the join `ON` condition:

```
SELECT acc.name,
       s.t_end
FROM ACCOUNT acc 
LEFT JOIN SUBSCRIPTION s ON acc.id = s.account_id AND 
                            s.t_start <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AND 
                            s.t_end > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
WHERE acc.id = 1
```

Also, it is generally a **good practice** to put as many conditions as possible into the JOIN `ON` conditions, as it increases readability of the queries. It will be much easier to change these queries as well, in case the Join type is being changed.

Comment: To echo this, you will almost always want to put as many conditions as possible into your `JOIN` conditions, because (besides resolving this particular issue), it usually makes your queries far easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

you are applying where condition on subscription table , so the because of the where condition the left join behaves like an inner join.

Try eliminating the where condition, if you can't  you can use below query-

```
SELECT acc.name,
       s.t_end
FROM ACCOUNT acc 
LEFT JOIN 
(select account_id,t_end from SUBSCRIPTION 
where 
     t_start <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
and  t_end > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
) s
ON acc.id = s.account_id
WHERE acc.id = 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "eliminating the `WHERE` condition"?  Clearly the conditions are overall necessary, so they have to go somewhere....

Comment: in the query which i have added in my answer, i have put the where condition in a subset and then took a left join with account table.Try executing the query you will get the desired results.

Comment: I know it will.  Depending on how smart the optimizer is, you might even get the same plan.  Generally, though, it's better to avoid the nesting if you can, because of the complication.  Your statement made it seem like you would be removing the conditions entirely.

Comment: yes, correct the nesting can be avoided and the where condition can be simply added in the join condition.